# Projecting Landsat image correctly using Build Virtual Raster

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, ndvi, landsat

I am trying to make one complete image using B4 images from USGS and another using B3 images to then calculate NDVI. The issue I'm having is a single image not lining up in the same projection (see image below, bottom right image needs to be bottom left). I have used Build Virtual Raster and my image and project CRS are both set to EPSG:2193 /  NZGD2000.

[image]

Comment: Is the problematic image really in EPSG:2193?